# Несовместимость проекта

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Создаю проект консольного приложения(с++) дома,  пишу код - все работает. Прихожу в колледж, открываю этот проект(и дома и в колледже Visual Studio 2017) - отваливаются все стандартные библиотеки, как я понял. Не работает функция rand(), а также появляется ~460 ошибок - из-за того, что в файлах внешних зависимостей большинство include-ов выдают ошибку типа "не удается открыть источник файл *** ".
Каждый раз приходится создавать новый проект, перекидывать и добавлять .cpp/.h файлы, что, конечно, неудобно и неправильно. 
Help, please!

Comment: Вполне вероятно что не стоит SDK/DDK или что-то типа того. Или руками в проекте что-то намудрили. Но вообще - гадание по кофейной гуще.

Comment: @Владимир в проекте никаких изменений, кроме добавления классов не было